# How to overlay sequence of frames on video using ffmpeg-python?

Tags: image-processing, ffmpeg, overlay, libav, ffmpeg-python

I tried below but it is only showing the background video.

```
background_video = ffmpeg.input( "input.mp4")
overlay_video = ffmpeg.input(f'{frames_folder}*.png', pattern_type='glob', framerate=25)
subprocess = ffmpeg.overlay(
                          background_video,
                          overlay_video,
                        ).filter("setsar", sar=1)
```

I also tried to assemble sequence of frames into .webm/.mov video but transparency is lost. video is taking black as background.

P.s - frame size is same as background video size. So no scaling needed.

### Edit

I tried @Rotem suggestions

> Try using single PNG image first

```
overlay_video =  ffmpeg.input('test-frame.png')
```

It's not working for frames generated by OpenCV but working for any other png image. This is weird, when I'm manually viewing these frames folder it's showing blank images([Link to my frames folder](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1i3Ktoo0C97OPaqnsH2DDoWECfKQJ2z_x?usp=sharing)).
But If I convert these frames into the video(see below) it is showing correctly what I draw on each frame.

```
output_options = {
                    'crf': 20,
                    'preset': 'slower',
                    'movflags': 'faststart',
                    'pix_fmt': 'yuv420p'
                }
ffmpeg.input(f'{frames_folder}*.png', pattern_type='glob', framerate=25 , reinit_filter=0).output(
                    'movie.avi',
                    **output_options
                ).global_args('-report').run()
```

> try creating a video from all the PNG images without overlay

It's working as expected only issue is transparency. Is there is way to create a transparent background video? I tried .webm/.mov/.avi but no luck.

> Add .global_args('-report') and check the log file

```
Report written to "ffmpeg-20221119-110731.log"
Log level: 48
ffmpeg version 5.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2022 the FFmpeg developers
  built with Apple clang version 13.1.6 (clang-1316.0.21.2.5)
  configuration: --prefix=/opt/homebrew/Cellar/ffmpeg/5.1 --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-version3 --cc=clang --host-cflags= --host-ldflags= --enable-ffplay --enable-gnutls --enable-gpl --enable-libaom --enable-libbluray --enable-libdav1d --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-librav1e --enable-librist --enable-librubberband --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsrt --enable-libtesseract --enable-libtheora --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvmaf --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-lzma --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-frei0r --enable-libass --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libspeex --enable-libsoxr --enable-libzmq --enable-libzimg --disable-libjack --disable-indev=jack --enable-videotoolbox --enable-neon
  libavutil      57. 28.100 / 57. 28.100
  libavcodec     59. 37.100 / 59. 37.100
  libavformat    59. 27.100 / 59. 27.100
  libavdevice    59.  7.100 / 59.  7.100
  libavfilter     8. 44.100 /  8. 44.100
  libswscale      6.  7.100 /  6.  7.100
  libswresample   4.  7.100 /  4.  7.100
  libpostproc    56.  6.100 / 56.  6.100
Input #0, image2, from './frames/*.png':
  Duration: 00:00:05.00, start: 0.000000, bitrate: N/A
  Stream #0:0: Video: png, rgba(pc), 1920x1080, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 25 tbn
Codec AVOption crf (Select the quality for constant quality mode) specified for output file #0 (movie.avi) has not been used for any stream. The most likely reason is either wrong type (e.g. a video option with no video streams) or that it is a private option of some encoder which was not actually used for any stream.
Codec AVOption preset (Configuration preset) specified for output file #0 (movie.avi) has not been used for any stream. The most likely reason is either wrong type (e.g. a video option with no video streams) or that it is a private option of some encoder which was not actually used for any stream.
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (png (native) -> mpeg4 (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
Output #0, avi, to 'movie.avi':
  Metadata:
    ISFT            : Lavf59.27.100
  Stream #0:0: Video: mpeg4 (FMP4 / 0x34504D46), yuv420p(tv, progressive), 1920x1080, q=2-31, 200 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbn
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc59.37.100 mpeg4
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/200000 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: N/A
frame=  125 fps= 85 q=31.0 Lsize=     491kB time=00:00:05.00 bitrate= 804.3kbits/s speed=3.39x    
video:482kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 1.772174%
```

To draw frame I used below.

```
for i in range(num_frames):
            transparent_img = np.zeros((height, width, 4),  dtype=np.uint8)
            cv2.line(transparent_img, (x1,y1), (x2,y2) ,(255, 255, 255), thickness=1, lineType=cv2.LINE_AA)
            self.frames.append(transparent_img)


## To Save each frame of the video in the given folder
for i, f in enumerate(frames):
    cv2.imwrite("{}/{:0{n}d}.png".format(path_to_frames, i, n=num_digits), f)
```

Comment: It's hard telling why it's not working... **1.** Try using single PNG image first (replace `f'{frames_folder}*.png', pattern_type='glob'` with `image_name.png`). **2.** For testing, try creating a video from all the PNG images without overlay. **3.** Try adding `-reinit_filter 0` flag: `overlay_video = ffmpeg.input(f'{frames_folder}*.png', pattern_type='glob', framerate=25, reinit_filter=0)`. **4.** Add `.global_args('-report')` like `.filter("setsar", sar=1).output('output.mp4').global_args('-report')`, and check the log file.

Comment: @Rotem Thanks.  I edited the question based on your suggestions. Please check.

Comment: **1.** Draw the line with alpha channel value 255. Example: `cv2.line(transparent_img, (10,10), (100,100), (255, 255, 255, 255), thickness=10, lineType=cv2.LINE_AA)`.  **2.** For creating video with transparent background try: `.webm` file, use `libvpx-vp9` video codec, and use `-pix_fmt yuva420p` - the "a" of yuva applis alpha (transparency) channel.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are answers to your two questions:

- For drawing a white line on BGRA image, use `(255, 255, 255, 255)` color instead of `(255, 255, 255)`.
  The last `255` applies alpha (transparency) channel value, and `255` makes the line fully opaque.
- For creating video with transparent background try: `.webm` file type, use `libvpx-vp9` video codec, and use `-pix_fmt yuva420p` - the `a` of `yuva` applies alpha (transparency) channel.

---

Here is a "self contained" code sample (please read the comments):

```python
import cv2
import numpy as np
import ffmpeg

# Create synthetic MP4 video file from testing
ffmpeg.input('testsrc=size=192x108:rate=1:duration=10', f='lavfi').output('tmp.mp4').overwrite_output().run()

transparent_img = np.zeros((108, 192, 4), np.uint8)

width, height, fps = 192, 108, 1

def make_sample_image(i):
    p = width//60
    img = np.zeros((height, width, 4), np.uint8)  # Fully transparent
    cv2.putText(img, str(i), (width//2-p*10*len(str(i)), height//2+p*10), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_DUPLEX, p, (255, 255, 255, 255), p*2)  # White number
    return img

# Create 10 PNG files with transparent background an white number (counter).
for i in range(1, 11):
    transparent_img = make_sample_image(i)
    cv2.imwrite(f'{i:03d}.png', transparent_img)


output_options = {  'vcodec' : 'libvpx-vp9',  # libvpx-vp9 supports transparency.
                    'crf': 20,
                    #'preset': 'slower',  # Not supported by libvpx-vp9
                    #'movflags': 'faststart',  # Not supported by WebM
                    'pix_fmt': 'yuva420p'  # yuva420p includes transparency.
                }

frames_folder = './'

# Create video with transparency:
# reinit_filter=0 is required, only if the PNG images have different characteristics (example: some are RGB and some RGBA).
# Use %03d.png instead of glob pattern, becuase my Windows version of FFmpeg doesn't support glob pattern.
ffmpeg.input(f'{frames_folder}%03d.png', framerate=fps, reinit_filter=0).output(
                    'movie.webm',  # WebM container supports transparency
                    **output_options
                ).global_args('-report').overwrite_output().run()


# Overlay the PNG on top of tmp.mp4
background_video = ffmpeg.input( "tmp.mp4")
overlay_video = ffmpeg.input(f'{frames_folder}%03d.png', framerate=fps)
subprocess = ffmpeg.overlay(
                          background_video,
                          overlay_video,
                        ).filter("setsar", sar=1)

subprocess.output('overlay_video.webm', **output_options).global_args('-report').overwrite_output().run()
```

Comment: Thanks Rotem for your help. Drawing line with alpha value works perfectly.